# Can not send POST request in Postman

Tags: rest, postman

My POST request body (raw form) in Postman looks like -

```
{
    "issueDescription" : "New issue reported",
    "type" : "Managed services",
    "priority" : "LOW",
    "description" : "This is a TEST, please ignore",
    "contactEmail" : "some.one@somewhere.com",
    "contactName" : "abc",
    "partnerTicketID" : "IN00012345"
}
```

I have Header specified as 'Content-Type = 'application/json'

The URL/endpoint is correctly specified - 'https://somecompany.com/rest/incident/

When clicked 'SEND', it gives following error (response) -

```
//
<rsp code="error">
    <msg>The Object passed in should not be null.</msg>
</rsp>
//
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the API is responding with this error. Are you sure the request is correct (considering the API contract)?

Comment: I am pretty sure error is not postman-related. You need to check w/ the owner of this API what is missing/wrong in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to provide more information about the endpoint you're sending the request to? What kind of object is it expecting? Is it expecting a json string?

Comment: Please post comments above where it says "add a comment". This is not an answer.

Comment: The end point is https://services/sec.xyz.com/rest/Incidents. In Postman the header is specified as 'Content-type' = 'application/json'

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I didn't realize I was making a mistake. I can't make a comment there yet until I earn more reputation, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `rest/incident/`API method returned an error message specifying that `The Object passed in should not be null.`

But that error message is very vague and you haven't included the API method code, so we can't tell you which property should be specified.

I recommend that you either read the API code or talk to the developer responsible for that code to understand which property you should specify.